# How do I spawn a Skeleton spawner?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I need to spawn in a spawner, what's the command? I have already tried a few times and can't get the command right.

Comment: Flagging as unclear because the question lacks an edition tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to set a block to a skeleton spawner:

```
/setblock <pos> minecraft:spawner{SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:skeleton"}}
```